# How to Filter array of objects based on a field inside one object?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an array of this form:

```
[
  {
    username: '',
    id: '',
    moreInfo: {
      infoDate: ''
    }
  }
]
```

And I need to filter based on the infoDate, whether it's in between two specific dates.

I have a function that accepts the object, and the field to search range by and returns :

```
return resultDate >= fromDate && resultDate <= thruDate;
```

But how do I filter such array . 
I tried

```
userData.filter(userData => functionthatFiltersDate(userData.moreInfo, {from,thru}, 'infoDate')
```

The functionthatFiltersDate is a function that accepts an object as input and dates to check range :

```
functionthatFiltersDate = (
  result,
  { fromDate, thruDate },
  fieldName
) => {
  let resultDate = result[fieldName];
  if (!isDate(resultDate)) {
    resultDate = moment(result[fieldName]).toDate();
  }
  if  (!isDate(fromDate)) {
    fromDate = moment(fromDate).toDate();
  }
  if (!isDate(thruDate)) {
    thruDate = moment(thruDate).toDate();
  }
  return resultDate >= fromDate && resultDate <= thruDate;
};
```

How do I filter though for an array of objects, based on another object property that's inside?
Any help  is appreciated!

Comment: Your code works? You know that `filter` returns a new array?

Comment: @JonasW. It works when I have a different array of objects , like :
`[{name:'', date:''}, {name:'', date:''}` , not the date being inside another object

Comment: `userData.moreInfo,` must be`user.moreInfo`

Comment: Ah sorry, I do write it correctly in the code, I was just trying to put a mock array here to shorten it. But the filtering doesn't work. I get empty array.

Comment: Maybe because `from` isnt `fromDate` ?! You made so many typos while "simplifying" your code that its impossible to tell what the root cause is in your original code

Answer (score -1):

call your function this way:

```
function fooBar(item ){
    // ....
    // return truthy condition
};

var result = arr.filter(fooBar);
```

-

Passing argument to the filter function:

```
const fruits = ['apple', 'banana', 'grapes', 'mango', 'orange'];

/**
 * Array filters items based on search criteria (query)
 */
const filterItems = (query) => {
  return fruits.filter((el) =>
    el.toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) > -1
  );
}

console.log(filterItems('ap')); // ['apple', 'grapes']
console.log(filterItems('an')); // ['banana', 'mango', 'orange']
```

Source: [Mozilla Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

-

Filtering array based on nested values:

```
var arr = [
 {foo: 'item1', nested: {nestedFoo: 'returnThis'} },
 {foo: 'item2', nested: {nestedFoo: 'notThis'} },
];

var result = arr.filter(item => item.nested.nestedFoo == 'returnThis');
// result variable now contains an array with one object
console.log(result) // array
console.log(result[0]) // object
console.log(result[0].foo) // 'item1'
```

[Refer to this question for explanation on how to access nested values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

-

Making it more clear:

```
var arr = [
  {
    username: '',
    id: '',
    moreInfo: {
      infoDate: ''
    }
  },
  {
    username: '',
    id: '',
    moreInfo: {
      infoDate: ''
    }
  },
 ...
];

const filterItems = (fromDate, thruDate, fieldName) => {
  return arr.filter((item) =>
    item.moreInfo.infoDate >= fromDate && item.moreInfo.infoDate < thruDate
  );
}
```

Comment: Why didn't you use OP's example for your answer? It would have been easier to follow with just a few changes from the original code.

Comment: As stated by OP in the comments under his questions, he mocked the original code in order to simplify the question and a specific answer may be too narrow. This might also help OP with a better understanding of the concept

Comment: @Enrico Thank you, but you are filtering ... if the word contains those letters?
What I can't do is if I have an array of objects, and then that array has an object within an object.. as stated in the example, how to filter based of one field value.

Comment: My function can even be ignored for simplification, I just don't know how to filter when the field I need to filter from is that deeply nested.

Comment: I don't think that some samples copied from MDN are able to solve a specific problem with the code.

Comment: OP has problems using the filter function and accessing nested properties. The code I provided solves both. Also, I'm providing more than mdn examples.